# how to sort the file in awk

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

i have a small problem. i need to sort a file according to the certain starting string of the file. for example in this form according to digits 04, 05 or 06:

```
04..............
................
................
05..............
................
................
06..............
................
................ etc..
```

here is my awk code: http://pastebin.com/dLsWkV3q

or just here:

```
echo "starting...input file"
read file
echo "reading file..."                                                  

echo "... now sorting..."
cat $file | awk '{
if($1=="04"){
print >> "04_file.txt";
}
if($1=="05"){
print >> "05_file.txt";
 }

if($1=="06"){
print >> "06_file.txt";
 }
}'

echo "finished, bye?"
read wait
echo "bye"
```

the goal is that i need multiple files as a result which contain only corresponding blocks, for the example above: as a result i will have 3 files. `04_file.txt`, `05_file.txt` and `06_file.txt`. AND `05_file.txt` doesnot have any line from 04 block. final `04_file.txt` file will have only this:

```
04..............
................
................
```

my problem is that it is saving other blocks also into 04_file.txt..

i will appreciate any help. thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like you could do this with `csplit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the only lines starting with 04, 05 etc. are the lines separating the different blocks:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { mode="unknown" }
    /^04/ { mode="04" }
    /^05/ { mode="05" }
    /^06/ { mode="06" }
          { if (mode != "unknown") print $0 >> sprintf("%s_file.txt", mode)}' < $file
```

`awk` is basically an environment to execute actions depending on patterns. Every pattern-action statement has the form

```
pattern { action }
```

In its most simple form a pattern is a regular expression matching the current input line. BEGIN is a special case which "matches" before the input is read and there is also an END "pattern" which gets executed after the input file is consumed.

On execution `awk` reads the input file line by line and executes all actions where the pattern matches the line. In the code above the `mode` variable is set if the input line begins (`^`) with 04, 05 etc. The last line (without the pattern) matches to all lines and just writes the whole line to the corresponding file.

I'll try to summarize this in some pseudo code:

```
mode := "unknown"
for each line of input do
    if line starts with 04 then set mode to 04 endif
    if line starts with 05 then set mode to 05 endif
    if line starts with 06 then set mode to 06 endif

    # mode is now either "unknown" if no 04/05/06 pattern has been read
    # from the file yet or holds the most recently read block start (04/05/06)

    if mode is not "unknown" then
        append whole line to file named 'mode'_file.txt
    endif
endfor
```

If you want to go further have a look at the man page or browse the web for `awk` introduction. There you also can learn more about the *pattern* part which can do much more than just match the current input line as in the example above.

---

In case all blocks start with two digits (any digits) the code above can be shortened to

```
awk '
    BEGIN { mode="unknown" }
    /^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/ { mode=substr($0, 1, 2) }
          { if (mode != "unknown") print $0 >> sprintf("%s_file.txt", mode)}' < $file
```

Comment: yes, you are right, those lines starting with 04, 05 are separating the blocks.. can you please explain in brief what the code does? :(. i dont want to copy and paste..

Comment: so, ``if(mode!="unknown")`` means that if the current line is neither 04 nor 05, then it will take last mode as a file name and writes the current line into that file, right?

Comment: No, the last line doesn't have a pattern (the part in front of the {}) and gets executed for every input line. I didn't know whether your input file doesn't start with a 04/05/06 line. That's why I set mode to "unknown" at the beginning and only start writing to dd_file.txt once a 04/05/06 line has been read.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, but what if 'aba' is the new line. mode isnot 'aba', then it writes to which mode file?

Comment: mode stays the same unless a new 04/05/06 is encountered in the file. So if 05 is on the line above 'aba' the line goes to 05_file.txt.

Comment: is it also possible to create a folder in this case before creating a file?

Comment: I would recommend to create the folder before calling the awk script and then using `sprintf("foldername/%s_file.txt", mode)` inside the script.

Comment: yeah, you are right, i can do this. but generally it is possible in awk to do this right? i will call shell command for this in awk inside?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14900/discussion-between-patrix-and-doniyor)